# UITableView Checklist with Details (Prevent Segue?)

Tags: swift, uitableview

## What Am I Trying to Accomplish?

I want to have a UITableView that displays items. The user should be able to click the item to indicate whether the item has been completed. I also want to give the user the ability to segue to a different ViewController with more details about an item in the list.

## What Is The Problem?

It's fairly straightforward to display items in a UITableView and allow user clicks to change the accessory to a checkmark. (There are hundreds of questions and answers on StackOverflow and dozens of tutorials available online.) My problem is that once I add the `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` function, clicking a list item performs the segue immediately after the call to `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, and I don't want that to happen.

## My Proposed Solution

I'd like to use the new **iOS 11** `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` functionality to allow a user to swipe a table cell for more details about the item. I have no problem getting this swipe to work -- I've used it successfully to perform other actions (*e.g.* delete, share) in other ViewControllers so I'm certain this must be possible.

## My Issues

1. I can't seem to "identify" who the `sender` is from *within* `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`, which means I'm not sure how I will be able to tell if the function is being called from the `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` instead of the `didSelectRowAt` function.
2. I'm not sure how to prevent the call to `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` on every `didSelectRowAt` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have Ctrl-dragged the segue directly from the tableview cell to the destination VC so it gets performed immediately when you tap the cell.

A solution is to create the segue from VC to VC by ctrl-dragging from the yellow VC icon to the destination VC and give it an identifier:

[image]

Then perform the segue manually by calling `PerformSegue(withIdentifier: sender:)` where you can explicitly set the `sender`to anything you need to identify it in the destination.

Comment: Thanks, @zisoft! That solved the second issue. And I was able to solve the first issue by making the `sender` in the `prepare` function equal to the `indexPath` from within `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`. (I just needed to change the `prepare` function to `if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath`.